# Loading date from an input file through sqlloader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a requirement to load the "dates" from a text file. I have tried like this

```
OPTIONS(skip=1)
load data
infile 'mypath\sample.txt'
APPEND
into table sample
fields terminated by "|"
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    name                 CHAR(500) NULLIF (name=BLANKS)
   , update_date date    "MM/DD/RRRR HH:MI:SS" NULLIF (update_date=BLANKS)
)
```

My system date format is "6/21/2000 8:29:58 AM"
It is not showing any error in the BAD file. but 64 records were there in the bad file. please help me.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you posted a few sample input lines; anyway, using the following example, it works fine in my case. Have a look, compare it with your attempt, make changes (if needed).

First, a table:

```
SQL> create table sample
  2    (name        varchar2(30),
  3     update_date date);

Table created.

SQL>
```

Control file (which includes sample data):

```
options (skip=1)
load data
infile *
replace
into table sample
fields terminated by '|' trailing nullcols
(
 name,
 update_date "to_date(:update_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss am')"
)
begindata
 name  |    update_date
little | 6/21/2000 8:29:58 AM
foot   | 12/21/2007 10:15:12 PM
```

Loading session:

```
M:\a1_maknuto>sqlldr little/foot@orcl control=test19.ctl log=test19.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Pon Sij 8 07:17:52 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 1
Commit point reached - logical record count 2

M:\a1_maknuto>
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from sample;

NAME                           UPDATE_DATE
------------------------------ -------------------
little                         21.06.2000 08:29:58
foot                           21.12.2007 22:15:12

SQL>
```

[EDIT: how to subtract 12 hours]

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss am';

Session altered.

SQL> with test as
  2    (select to_date('12/19/2017 12:49:48 PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss am') col
  3     from dual
  4    )
  5  select
  6    col,
  7    col - 12/24 sub_12_hours
  8  from test;

COL                    SUB_12_HOURS
---------------------- ----------------------
12/19/2017 12:49:48 PM 12/19/2017 12:49:48 AM

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks. Here I'm posting some sample data: 12/7/2017 5:39:34 AM, 12/7/2017 5:39:34 AM, 12/19/2017 3:17:26 AM, 12/19/2017 3:29:27 AM,

Comment: So, did you try **my** control file with **your** data? When I said "sample data", I expected NAME and DATE (as that's what you are importing). Anyway, you'd rather try it yourself. Say if it doesn't work, and - if it doesn't - post excerpt of the LOG file which explains what happened.

Comment: Yes. I have tried and It worked. Thanks. I have one more question.I have the data like "12/19/2017 12:49:48 PM". how can I get AM in the place of PM?

Comment: Subtract 12 hours. However, if you got PM in the input file, you'd rather make sure that you receive valid data. Because, how are you supposed to know whether it is AM or PM?

Comment: Now, I have to manually update the column using update statement

Comment: As I said: subtract 12 hours. I edited my answer so that you'd see how to do it (comment isn't practical for posting code).